# Arabic Shapepar

Tags: arabic, shapepar

I want to use a text in Arabic in a form that works very well with a text in French or English but I can not. Can you please help me?
Thank you

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside,final]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{flafter,placeins}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,color,soulutf8,longtable,colortbl,setspace,ifthen,xspace,url,pdflscape}
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage[]{utf8}
\setcode{utf8}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{arabtex}
    \def\mosqdoor{%
      {15}% Horizontal center
      {0}b{15}\\% Text begins at x=15, y=0
      {1}t{13}{4}\\%
      {2}t{10.5}{9}\\%
      {3}t{8.5}{13}\\%
      {4}t{7.2}{15.6}\\%
      {5}t{6.3}{17.4}\\%
      {6}t{5.5}{19}\\%
      {7}t{4.8}{20.4}\\%
      {8}t{4.3}{21.4}\\%
      {9}t{4.1}{21.8}\\%
      {9.5}t{3.9}{22.2}\\%
      {10}t{4.1}{21.8}\\%
      {11}t{4.3}{21.4}\\%
      {12}t{4.5}{21}\\%
      {13}t{5}{20}\\%
      {14}t{5.8}{18.4}\\%
      {15}t{7}{16}\\%
      {17}t{7}{16}\\%
      {18}t{7}{16}\\% <<
      {18.1}t{6}{18}\\%
      {19}t{6}{18}\\%
      {20}t{5}{20}\\%
      {29}t{5}{20}\\%
      {30}e{15}%
    }

    \begin{document}

    \Shapepar{\mosqdoor}
    {I see now the many ways of creating beautiful forms. As you use shapepar, text may be made to appear in geometric shapes and arrangements. Very nice are the things you can do. I see now the many ways of creating beautiful forms. As you use shapepar, text may be made to appear in geometric shapes and arrangements. Very nice are the things you can do I see now the many ways of creating beautiful forms. As you use shapepar, text may be made to appear in geometric shapes and arrangements. Very nice are the things you can do. I see now the many ways of creating beautiful forms. As you use shapepar, text may be made to appear in geometric shapes and arrangements. Very nice are the things you can do.}\par

    \Shapepar{\mosqdoor}
    {\<تـسـألـنـي عــن أسـبــاب فــرحـتــي أولــهــا أنــتو ثـانـيها أنــت  و آخــرها أنــت  و كـل فرحــــي.أنــت ،  أنـــت ، أنـــت   فـلا تلومنــي إذا بكـــت عينـــي عليــــك أو خفــــق الفــــؤاد و إزداد شـــــوقـاً إليـــــك أو نـــــزف قلبـــي و مــــات مدفونـــــاً بيـــــــن يديـــــــــك فـمــــــا إشــــــتقت لأحــــــد كمــــــا إشـــــــتقت إليــــــــك .>}\par

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please kick out all packages that are not related to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This works with `arabluatex`. The file needs to be compiled with `lualatex` of course.  As it is, the shapepar needs some more work, but at least it is a start.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{shapepar}
\usepackage{arabluatex}

\def\mosqdoor{%
  {15}% Horizontal center
  {0}b{15}\\% Text begins at x=15, y=0
  {1}t{13}{4}\\%
  {2}t{10.5}{9}\\%
  {3}t{8.5}{13}\\%
  {4}t{7.2}{15.6}\\%
  {5}t{6.3}{17.4}\\%
  {6}t{5.5}{19}\\%
  {7}t{4.8}{20.4}\\%
  {8}t{4.3}{21.4}\\%
  {9}t{4.1}{21.8}\\%
  {9.5}t{3.9}{22.2}\\%
  {10}t{4.1}{21.8}\\%
  {11}t{4.3}{21.4}\\%
  {12}t{4.5}{21}\\%
  {13}t{5}{20}\\%
  {14}t{5.8}{18.4}\\%
  {15}t{7}{16}\\%
  {17}t{7}{16}\\%
  {18}t{7}{16}\\% <<
  {18.1}t{6}{18}\\%
  {19}t{6}{18}\\%
  {20}t{5}{20}\\%
  {29}t{5}{20}\\%
  {30}e{15}%
}

\begin{document}

\Shapepar{\mosqdoor}{I see now the many ways of creating beautiful
  forms. As you use shapepar, text may be made to appear in geometric
  shapes and arrangements. Very nice are the things you can do. I see
  now the many ways of creating beautiful forms. As you use shapepar,
  text may be made to appear in geometric shapes and
  arrangements. Very nice are the things you can do I see now the many
  ways of creating beautiful forms. As you use shapepar, text may be
  made to appear in geometric shapes and arrangements. Very nice are
  the things you can do. I see now the many ways of creating beautiful
  forms. As you use shapepar, text may be made to appear in geometric
  shapes and arrangements. Very nice are the things you can do.}\par

\Shapepar{\mosqdoor}{\txarb{تـسـألـنـي عــن أسـبــاب فــرحـتــي
أولــهــا أنــتو ثـانـيها أنــت وآخــرها أنــت وكـل فرحــــي. أنــت،
أنـــت، أنـــت فـلا تلومنــي إذا بكـــت عينـــي عليــــك أو
خفــــق الفــــؤاد وإزداد شـــــوقـاً إليـــــك أو نـــــزف
قلبـــي ومــــات مدفونـــــاً بيـــــــن يديـــــــــك فـمــــــا
إشــــــتقت لأحــــــد كمــــــا إشـــــــتقت إليــــــــك.}}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please note that I didn't say that it can't be done with `arabtex`.